# Understanding morphisms in FinSet

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I'm looking at the skeletal **FinSet** category ; there is one object for each natural number $n$ (including $n=0$), and a morphism from $m$ to $n$ is an $m$-tuple $(f_0, \ldots, f_{m-1})$ of numbers satisfying $0 \leq f_i \lt n. $ (stolen from http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FinSet)

If I understand it correctly it, my objects are $\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,1,2\}, \ldots$ and so on. But I'm having trouble understanding the morphisms. Exactly what happens when I go from a object $m$ to an object $n$, when $\left\vert{n}\right\vert >\left\vert{m}\right\vert$? Do the $f_i$:s in my $m$-tuple actually do anything to the members of $m$ or do I just simply end up in $n$, in a sense making $m$ as big as $n$ in a transformation? Am I Missing Something?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Morphisms need not be maps; what's required is the composition law and the existence of identities.

Comment: @egreg something just "clicked" in my head, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that in a category $C$, the morphisms do not need to be functions. Also, you can define categories in an object-free (if I'm correct, this is cited in Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*).

In the category $\mathbf{FinSet}$, what is done is "identifying" each finite set $X$ with its size $|X|$ (or the object corresponding to it). We do not lose information of $X$ (as a set) because two finite sets are isomorphic (in the usual sense) iff they have the same number of elements.

So, given an object $n$ of $\mathbf{FinSet}$, we may think of $n$ as a set with $n$ elements, say $n=\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ (this can actually be done if we work with finite ordinals). In this sense, the set of functions (morphisms) $f:m\to n$ is in bijection with the set of $m$-tuples as in your question, by the bijection $f\mapsto (f(0),\ldots,f(m-1))$.

Comment: It is more natural to think of objects as finite cardinals than to think of them as finite ordinals, because the cardinals (of arbitrary size) give rise to a skeleton of $\mathbf{Set} $, whereas ordinals form a skeleton in the category of well-ordered sets.

Answer (score 2):

Just view the morphisms as functions from your sets, with normal function composition. So if $M=\{0,1,2\}$, $N=\{0,1,2,3\}$, the morphism $(2,3,0)$ from $M$ to $N$ denotes the function that maps $0$ to $2$, $1$ to $3$, and $2$ to $0$.